# The intuitive meaning of integrals

Tags: calculus

I am an engineering student and i always encounter problems that needs integrals I know that integral is area under the curve , etc.... but till now i could not develop and intuitive meaning for integration. does integration rely only on the idea of area under the curve. do the physics laws that are based on integration like for example the that the work is the integral of the F in infinitesimal distance was proved by the idea of the area under the curve or is there an intuitive way that i could understand the integration through it?